# How does a particular rewrite work?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, yii, url-rewriting, apache2

Yii framework works with paths of form `http://foo.bar/index.php/foo/bar/baz`.

There is an [article](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#hiding-x-23x) which tells how to hide the `index.php` using `mod_rewrite`

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

The probles is that I do not understand how this rewrite works when rewriting `http://foo.bar/foo/bar/baz`

1. The rewrite engine receives `foo/bar/baz`
2. `.` matches `foo/bar/baz`
3. Since `2` is true the two conditions are checked too and they are matched
4. `foo/bar/baz` is replaced with `index.php`
5. The next iteration of rewrite does not change the path since the file actually exists and the first condition does not match
6. Internal redirect to `index.php` is performed

What I can not get is why I can see the `http://foo.bar/index.php/foo/bar/baz` page when the redirect is made to the `http://foo.bar/index.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok The reason for this is simple. If you do a rewrite to a new location, the whole url-path and all query-parts are getting set relative to the new file-location. So during your first iteration the file does not exist and therefore the whole path is set relative to index.php.

In detail rewrite can do two things:

1. map an url to a file
2. redirect to an all new url

the first one is a remap and therefore NO NEW REQUEST. this is what we use here. the old request gets mapped to index.php and therefore your answer is: no, the same request is used.
If we redirect to an url though (no matter if on same server or not) a new request gets fired. See the intro-text here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

After that index.php is called (front-controller-pattern) and yii uses the path and query-params to locate the corresponding controller and action. could be easily done like this:

```
<?php
//remove slashes
$str = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
//remove index
$str = trim($str, 'index.php');
//remove slashes
$str = trim($str, '/');

//get parts
$urlParts = explode('/', $str);

//fill vars
$module     = count($urlParts) == 2 ? $urlParts[0] : null;
$controller = count($urlParts) == 2 ? $urlParts[0] : $urlParts[1];
$action     = count($urlParts) == 2 ? $urlParts[1] : $urlParts[2];

//call controller / action via reflection HERE
```

If yii finds three party it looks for module/controller/action. if two are found it looks for controller/action. The query-parameters are passed to the corresponding function-params of the action.

et voilà...but back to your question: really just read about how the front-controller-pattern is realized in php. you'll find a lot of very detailed answers on google.

just tell me if you need more details!

Comment: refined the code a little...this is really just to give you an idea how this could be done! of course you would worry about wrong number of parts etc. but this is not subject of this answer. hope it helps :)!

Comment: Does Apache make a new HTTP request to the 'http://foo.bar/index.php` while internal redirect? If yes how does `index.php` know the original path `foo/bar/baz`?

Comment: I am interested in what actually happens *before* php script is executed. Does Apache make a new HTTP request internally or it keeps all HTTP headers from the original request and passes them to the new file?

Comment: As far as I know it just redirects it and keeps the request with modified params (i have to admit this is a deep question). the second part i can answer you. if you create a php script containing nothing more than this:

`echo 'req url: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and you call it with myscript.php/bla/test/ then `/bla/test/` will be part of it. within index.php you can just get the request_url like so and do whatever you want with it. there's a lot of $_SERVER vars which can be really helpful as they contain all the request stuff! 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: I digged deeper and completed my original answer. just learned something as well ;)

Comment: Well, now when we know that Apache "maps" the original HTTP request to a different file during `internal rewrite` that is quite obvious how Yii retrieves the original request path from HTTP headers. My mistake was that I used to think that a new HTTP request with new headers is performed internally by Apache. Thank you, the issue is solved.